# Sharepoint contenttype columns -> types

Tags: content-type, visual-studio, column, content-deployment

Does anybody have a list of all internal "type" names of contenttype - columns in SP2010?

I am creating a custom contenttype in VS and really don't have an idea where to get them from. I already found out "HTML" as type for Full HTML, but I need all of them.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way would be to open up the xml of the out of box feature which provisions columns in SharePoint site.

Got to C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\fields.

The 3 xml files fieldswss.xml, fieldswss2.xml and fieldswss3.xml contain the definitions of all the OOB columns in SharePoint. You can easily search for a column and find its type.

Be very careful not to accidentally modify any of the files there.

Answer (score 1):

there's some POSH script that'll output a Site Collection's Content Types & Fields and their properties onto a CSV file -
http://aarebrot.net/blog/2008/08/powershell-retrieve-content-types-and-column-fields/

Comment: Thank you for this script, very helpful - indeed, bookmarked :P

Answer (score 1):

The list of standard SharePoint field types [can be found on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms437580.aspx) (scroll way down to the `Type` attribute).